# how to export loadrunner analysis report with extension .lra to pdf file

Tags: loadrunner

I am using loadrunner version 11. I wanted to know how to export my analysis file which has extension .lra to a file with extension .pdf. The file is saved with either .lrr extension or .lra extension. I want to export the analysis file so that people not having access to loadrunner controller can also read the analysis report.

Answer (score 0):

The LRA file is a text file which points to all of the resources used for the analysis session ([L]oad[R]unner [A]nalysis).   Have you considered the following?

- Use VUGEN to export the results to a word document and then print that to a PDF using any number of available PDF drivers
- Use the database file which holds the raw data along with a LaTeX file with PHP tags to speak directly to the datastore, output a LaTeX document which is prepopulated with data and graphs from your LaTeX template and the data sourced with the PHP inclusions, then outputing that LaTeX document to PDF.    This can be automated via batch.